# Hardware acceleration is making chrome laggy , with NVIDIA 390.48 in UBUNTU 18.04 , how to solve?

Tags: nvidia, google-chrome, 18.04, hardware-acceleration

Reproduce: mouse movement raise HIGH cpu usage and mouse lags, especially on youtube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+1. Here is [bug-report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1768199/). Feel free to mark that this bug also affects you.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1)  Use Chromium instead.  I've seen your same issue within google-chrome-stable but everything is clean within Chromium.

Option 2) If you installed NVIDIA 390.48 directly, uninstall it and then re-enabling the driver using the Additional Drivers tab within Software & Updates.